# How to select from whereIn clause using Laravel Eloquent ORM or Query Builder?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'd like to get value by the following MySQL using Eloquent ORM.

MySQL Query -

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `is_super_admin` = 1 OR `is_partner` = 1 
OR `is_admin` = 1 OR `id` IN 
(select `user_id` from `site_userrole_mapper` where `is_site_owner` = 1)
```

Laravel Query (It's not working) -

```
Users::Where('is_super_admin', '=', 1)
        ->orWhere('is_partner', '=', 1)
        ->orWhere('is_admin', '=', 1)
        ->orWhereIn('id', [
            DB::table('site_userrole_mapper')
            ->select('user_id')
            ->where('is_site_owner', '=', 1)
            ->get()
            //Here get() returns an object and we're not able compare it with id
        ])
        ->get();
```

I just want to convert above MySQL query in Eloquent ORM. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you define model for ```site_userrole_mapper``` table?

Comment: Nope, I didn't define the model for site_userrole_mapper. That's why I have used table clause in site_userrole_mapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one,

change this query and pluck `user_id`

```
whereIn('id',[
DB::table('site_userrole_mapper')
        ->select('user_id')
        ->where('is_site_owner', '=', 1)
        ->get()
   ])
```

to

```
whereIn('id',
DB::table('site_userrole_mapper')
        ->where('is_site_owner', '=', 1)
        ->pluck('user_id')
      )
```

Comment: Great, and Congrats

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
Users::Where('is_super_admin', '=', 1)
    ->orWhere('is_partner', '=', 1)
    ->orWhere('is_admin', '=', 1)
    ->orWhereIn('id', 
        DB::table('site_userrole_mapper')
        ->where('is_site_owner', '=', 1)
        ->pluck('user_id')
        //Here get return an object and we're not able compare it with id
    )
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `->toArray()` on that object to convert it to an array so that the `IN` clause works properly:

```
Users::where('is_super_admin', '=', 1)
        ->orWhere('is_partner', '=', 1)
        ->orWhere('is_admin', '=', 1)
        ->orWhereIn('id', 
            DB::table('site_userrole_mapper')
            ->select('user_id')
            ->where('is_site_owner', '=', 1)
            ->get()->toArray()
        )->get();
```